# Jenkins export build number to file

Tags: jenkins

I'm using the Export parameters plugin.
I want to export the build number to a file.

I'm using string parameter:

```
jenkins-build
${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Export to properties file using key:

```
jenkins-build
```

But the exported file does not update the build number. I get:

```
jenkins-build=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your configuration using these plugins should work if you manually input `BUILD_NUMBER` at the time of triggering a build. However, you may also use below build steps for your requirement.

**Linux Platforms - Execute shell**

```
echo "jenkins-build=$BUILD_NUMBER" > /path/to/file.properties
```

[image: Shell]

**Windows Platform - Execute windows batch command**

```
echo jenkins-build=%BUILD_NUMBER% > Drive:\path\to\file.properties
```

[image: Batch]

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `echo "jenkins-build=${BUILD_NUMBER}" >> /path/to/jenkins-build` it will stack every build number to the file in a following manner:

```
 jenkins-build=1
 jenkins-build=2
 jenkins-build=3
 and so on....
```

If you only want to store the current build number then follow these steps:

Create a file called `jenkins-build` where you are going to store the current build number.

Then create a `jenkins-build.tmp` file and add `jenkins-build=${BUILD_NUMBER}` to this.

Then use the `envsubst` command to substitute `${BUILD_NUMBER}` with the build number value.

Then store the content to another file i.e. `jenkins-build` using the following command:

```
envsubst '${BUILD_NUMBER}' < "/path/to/jenkins-build.tmp" > "/path/to/jenkins-build"
```

Add the above command in `Execute shell` section of your Jenkins job.